# Running React app in Docker (Basic question)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile

There's quite a few questions in SO about running a React App in Docker, and while I believe I'm following the instructions to the letter, it's still not working for me and was wondering if anyone has a clear solution.

In short I have the following in my Dockerfile

```
ARG VARIANT="14-buster"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/typescript-node:0-${VARIANT}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
```

This works, but I have to manually run `NPM START` in the terminal within VSCode in order for my browser to open http://localhost:3000

I've read in various posts that either adding `RUN npm start` or `RUN ['CMD', 'START']`will achieve what I want, but absolutely none of those work at all.  Sure enough the only to make it work is running `NPM START` in the terminal of VSCode.

Is there something utterly obvious I'm missing?  I just want to be able to have this app running in a container, without VSCode, and if I need access to it, just type http://localhost:3000 in my browser and get access to the Dockerized image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that adding at the end of your dockerfile the following step `CMD npm start` or `CMD ["npm", "start"]`, [here you go more information](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)